# Building a Java Web Start App for Multiple Codebases

Tags: java-web-start, codebase

I have a Java Web Start application for which the JNLP is generated dynamically. The JWS application is built in NetBeans, which offers me several options RE the codebase for this app, including not specifying one. But so far, I've been using the "User defined" option, i.e., I've been specifying the codebase within every build. My question is, what do I need to do to get my app to run if I don't specify a codebase? Right now, I have to rebuild with a different codebase for each environment in which I want to run this application, which is not ideal. But if I don't specify the codebase, the JWS application won't run. I'm currently writing the dynamic JNLP to a ServletOutputStream. Would I have to write it out to an actual file first before I could use it?

Comment: *"..several options RE the codebase for this app, including not specifying one."* AFAIU, that is obsolete information. For security reasons, it is now required not only to specify a code base explicitly, but to write the code base into the (digitally signed) Jar files. The upshot is that it will be necessary to build the app. (or at least a JNLP and 'launcher' Jar - the rest of the APIs it uses *can* be in an extension on another site) specific to each site.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Andrew; I guess my colleagues and I will have to roll with the punches on this one...